# Margin in output document generated by asymptote

Tags: margins, asymptote

In the following figure, generated using `asymptote`, I am getting a PDF file while compiling in a LaTeX document.

[Labels and angles in crystal structure using Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121169/labels-and-angles-in-crystal-structure-using-asymptote/121197?noredirect=1#121197)

The problem is, there is huge whitespace around the figure which I cannot crop using `pdfcrop`. I have tried to convert it using `ImageMagick` to JPG or PNG but it is completely destroying the resolution of the image.

How can I get a PDF or image file with no excess white space around ?

Comment: If you have only a pdf file for the figure, you can crop it with Gimp for instance, no?

Comment: I have tried cropping with Gimp also .. resolution gets damaged drastically.

Comment: You can also use the trim feature of the when you include your pdf graphic if pdfcrop fails: `\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm]{picture.pdf}` where the dimensions are for left, bottom, right and top.

Comment: In this particular example, use `zoom=1` in  `currentprojection`.
Or interactively adjust the `3d` view to your needs with `asy -V <file>`.

Comment: \includegraphics[trim = 20mm 20mm 20mm 20mm,clip,width=\textwidth]{path/to/picture/pic.pdf}. This one worked.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, use `zoom=1` in `currentprojection`. 
Or interactively adjust the `3d` view to suit your needs with `asy -V <file>`.

Answer (score 1):

In general included graphics can easily be cropped, trimmed, scaled and rotated using the commands from the `graphicx` package. For your purpose

```
\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm]{picture.pdf}
```

might help. Here the dimensions are the amount that is trimmed from the left, bottom, right and top of the picture. A thorough description of more feature are given [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics).