# Draw molecule structure with torsion angles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, asymptote, chemistry, angle

I am trying to reproduce this figure in LaTeX:

[image: Torsion angles]

The packages that I have seen for annotating chemical structures do not seem to accomplish what I want (not to mention that my knowledge on chemical notation has vanished long time ago).

So, any hint on how to perform this with TikZ/Asymptote/similar package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) This reminds me of a blog post I had forgotten: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/drawing-molecules/

Comment: Thanks @cgnieder for the link, although it seems a little bit discouraging for solving the problem :(

Comment: @epsilone Well it sounds from that post as if `asymptote` is your best bet if you want something properly 3D relatively easily. What you've posted isn't exactly like that so you could probably do it in `tikz` fairly straightforwardly if that would be easier for you (e.g. you know `tikz` but not `asymptote`). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cfr Well I have not tried building the figure from scratch, I was looking for any hint on how to start working in a promising direction. As I have a little experience in using `tikz` maybe I should start with it.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141363/484) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114876/484).