# Plot with ragged lines

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I need to plot the ragged line between two specific points, similar to the following graph:[image]

I have done the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[smooth, domain=0:3] {1+sin(x+rand*10)};
\addplot[smooth, domain=3:6] {5-0.5*x+sin(x+rand*10)};
\addplot[smooth, domain=6:9] {2+sin(x+rand*10)};
\addplot[smooth, domain=0:3, dashed] {1};
\addplot[smooth, domain=3:9, dashed] {2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the lines are jumping at the point (6,2). Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239874/tikz-pgfplots-how-can-i-generate-a-figure-like-this-one, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143070/drawing-randomly-ragged-lines-in-technical-drawings or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147385/arbitrary-ragged-curves-for-phase-diagram-in-tikz could be a good starting point

Comment: You could use a single `\addplot` for this. Try `\addplot[smooth, domain=0:9, samples=150] {rand*0.2 + (x<3 ? 1 : (x<6 ? 5-0.5*x : 2))};`.

Comment: Thanks @Jake. And how can I remove the vertical line at x=3?

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted all segments connected. If you don't want the first and second segment to be connected, use separate `\addplot[smooth, domain=0:3, samples=50] {1+rand*0.2};
\addplot[smooth, domain=3:9, samples=100] {rand*0.2 + (x<6 ? 5-0.5*x : 2)};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Jake, this is the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis line style = very thick, smooth, no markers,
        axis lines= middle,
        ylabel=Price,  
        xlabel=Time,  
        xmax=10, xmin=-1,
        ymax=5, ymin=-1,
        ytickmax=0, 
        xtickmax=0, 
]
\addplot[smooth, domain=0:3, samples=20] {1+rand*0.3}; 
\addplot[smooth, domain=3:9, samples=40] {rand*0.3 + (x<6 ? 5-0.5*x : 2)};
\addplot[smooth, domain=0:3, dashed] {1};
\addplot[smooth, domain=3:9, dashed] {2};
\end{axis}
\node[draw] at (5,5) {Price Adjustment};
\node[draw] at (2.5,0) {Good News};
\draw[thick,->] (2.5, 0.5) -- (2.5, 1.5);
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,4.5) -- (4, 4);
\draw [blue,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(2.7,4.5) -- (4.4,3.1) node [black,midway] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I think you can [accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your own answer.