# TikZ: How to clip out random coil fragments?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, line, fill, pattern

Based on this answer from [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482471/78784) I am thinking about how to design a turbulent flow regime along a stream line within coarsed soil.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{gluon/.style={decorate, draw=magenta,
        decoration={coil,amplitude=20pt, segment length=25pt}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gluon, blue] (0,0) -- (10,0);%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

Maybe it would be possible to let those coils appear a bit more "fragmented", so they could visualize a turbulent flow regime like seen below. One could add several coil lines along the stream line and clip out random fragments of the coils, so somethink like this could appear:

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

What do you guys think about this? Would it be possible to remove random fragments anyhow?

Comment: Considering that the coil is formed from elliptical arcs, why not just use random elliptical arcs?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Great idea! How to go for this? :-)

Comment: A rectangular grid containing random arcs is easy.  The problem would be packing them into a tighter arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question hasn't got any answer in several days, here is something that may go in the "right" direction. It is a bit along the lines [John Kormylo is suggesting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/tikz-how-to-clip-out-random-coil-fragments#comment1221087_482934) and otherwise very similar to the [answer you are referring to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482471/78784). It just draws arcs with `in` and `out` being somewhat randomized.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta,bending} 
\newcounter{randarcs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[randarc/.style={out=\angA+90+\angB/6,in=\angA+90-\angB/6,
looseness=\lsns}]
%\draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\pgfmathsetseed{21}
\foreach \X in {1,...,100}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{-0.5+5*rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{-0.5+5*rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angA}{360*rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radA}{0.3+0.3*rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxp}{\myx+\radA*cos(\angA)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyp}{\myy+\radA*sin(\angA)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\angB}{360*sin(90*rnd)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lsns}{1+3*\radA}
%\typeout{\angA,\radA;\angB,\radB}
\path[-{Latex},name path=test-arc] 
(\myx,\myy) to[randarc] (\myxp,\myyp) ;
\def\HasIntersection{0}
\ifnum\X>1
 \foreach \Y in {1,...,\number\value{randarcs}}
 {\path[name intersections={of=\Y-arc and test-arc,total=\t},
 /utils/exec=\ifnum\t>0
  \xdef\HasIntersection{1}%\typeout{intersects}
 \fi];
 }
\fi
\ifnum\HasIntersection=0
    \stepcounter{randarcs}
    \draw[-] 
   (\myx,\myy) to[randarc] (\myxp,\myyp);
    \path[name path global=\number\value{randarcs}-arc]
   (\myx,\myy) to[randarc] (\myxp,\myyp)-- cycle;
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\typeout{\number\value{randarcs}\space arcs\space drawn.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are many ways in which one may customize/improve this, but I do not know your precise preferences, so I didn't do that here. Imposing a grace distance between the arcs seems feasible (busing `local bounding boxes`.