# How to draw vortices and streamlines over airfoil using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw some turbulent flow structures on an airfoil like below:
[image]

I could draw the airfoil using the following codes:

```
\newcounter{y}
\setcounter{y}{0}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \lbl / \fn in {
            /GEOM.dat}{
            \draw[yshift=-\arabic{y}cm,scale=8][rotate=-13.3]  {\lbl}
            plot file{\fn} -- cycle;
            \stepcounter{y}}   

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Different airfoils}
    \label{fig:foils}
\end{figure}
```

The GEOM.dat file contains:

```
1.0000000   -0.0118460
0.9967630   -0.0122598
0.9935710   -0.0126678
0.9903470   -0.0130790
0.9870920   -0.0134936
0.9838070   -0.0139123
0.9804910   -0.0143347
0.9771440   -0.0147608
0.9737650   -0.0151906
0.9703540   -0.0156243
0.9669100   -0.0160615
0.9634310   -0.0165022
0.9599160   -0.0169464
0.9563670   -0.0173941
0.9527830   -0.0178455
0.9491630   -0.0183005
0.9455070   -0.0187592
0.9418150   -0.0192216
0.9380870   -0.0196878
0.9343220   -0.0201578
0.9305200   -0.0206317
0.9266810   -0.0211097
0.9228060   -0.0215918
0.9188930   -0.0220781
0.9149430   -0.0225686
0.9109560   -0.0230635
0.9069310   -0.0235627
0.9028690   -0.0240664
0.8987680   -0.0245746
0.8946280   -0.0250873
0.8904480   -0.0256043
0.8862280   -0.0261257
0.8819660   -0.0266514
0.8776620   -0.0271813
0.8733150   -0.0277155
0.8689250   -0.0282540
0.8644910   -0.0287966
0.8600110   -0.0293433
0.8554850   -0.0298938
0.8509100   -0.0304480
0.8462850   -0.0310057
0.8416110   -0.0315669
0.8368850   -0.0321316
0.8321070   -0.0326996
0.8272760   -0.0332709
0.8223920   -0.0338455
0.8174530   -0.0344233
0.8124590   -0.0350043
0.8074080   -0.0355882
0.8023000   -0.0361751
0.7971340   -0.0367649
0.7919080   -0.0373574
0.7866220   -0.0379526
0.7812750   -0.0385505
0.7758660   -0.0391508
0.7703940   -0.0397536
0.7648580   -0.0403588
0.7592580   -0.0409663
0.7535910   -0.0415759
0.7478580   -0.0421876
0.7420560   -0.0428013
0.7361860   -0.0434167
0.7302450   -0.0440337
0.7242330   -0.0446523
0.7181490   -0.0452723
0.7119900   -0.0458933
0.7057570   -0.0465154
0.6994470   -0.0471382
0.6930590   -0.0477616
0.6865930   -0.0483853
0.6800460   -0.0490092
0.6734180   -0.0496330
0.6667070   -0.0502565
0.6599120   -0.0508794
0.6530310   -0.0515014
0.6460640   -0.0521223
0.6390070   -0.0527417
0.6318590   -0.0533590
0.6246180   -0.0539737
0.6172830   -0.0545853
0.6098490   -0.0551931
0.6023160   -0.0557962
0.5946790   -0.0563936
0.5869350   -0.0569842
0.5790800   -0.0575665
0.5711100   -0.0581391
0.5630220   -0.0587002
0.5548120   -0.0592481
0.5464750   -0.0597809
0.5380100   -0.0602968
0.5294140   -0.0607942
0.5206850   -0.0612715
0.5118220   -0.0617266
0.5028230   -0.0621574
0.4936880   -0.0625618
0.4844170   -0.0629379
0.4750110   -0.0632839
0.4655580   -0.0635951
0.4561160   -0.0638694
0.4466880   -0.0641064
0.4372800   -0.0643057
0.4278960   -0.0644667
0.4185410   -0.0645888
0.4092220   -0.0646718
0.3999440   -0.0647168
0.3907120   -0.0647250
0.3815330   -0.0646976
0.3724100   -0.0646358
0.3633480   -0.0645408
0.3543510   -0.0644130
0.3454240   -0.0642524
0.3365720   -0.0640592
0.3277970   -0.0638346
0.3191020   -0.0635800
0.3104910   -0.0632966
0.3019660   -0.0629854
0.2935290   -0.0626476
0.2851820   -0.0622842
0.2769250   -0.0618968
0.2687590   -0.0614870
0.2606830   -0.0610561
0.2526970   -0.0606056
0.2448020   -0.0601369
0.2369940   -0.0596511
0.2292740   -0.0591496
0.2216400   -0.0586335
0.2140890   -0.0581043
0.2066200   -0.0575632
0.1992300   -0.0570116
0.1919150   -0.0564506
0.1846750   -0.0558812
0.1775060   -0.0553043
0.1704110   -0.0547195
0.1633910   -0.0541265
0.1564490   -0.0535246
0.1495890   -0.0529128
0.1428160   -0.0522899
0.1361360   -0.0516547
0.1295560   -0.0510057
0.1230840   -0.0503415
0.1167260   -0.0496611
0.1104890   -0.0489637
0.1043800   -0.0482485
0.0984092   -0.0475143
0.0925859   -0.0467602
0.0869219   -0.0459849
0.0814304   -0.0451876
0.0761244   -0.0443672
0.0710167   -0.0435234
0.0661198   -0.0426562
0.0614448   -0.0417657
0.0569995   -0.0408529
0.0527910   -0.0399190
0.0488219   -0.0389655
0.0450887   -0.0379947
0.0415875   -0.0370087
0.0383116   -0.0360096
0.0352510   -0.0349996
0.0323961   -0.0339807
0.0297363   -0.0329547
0.0272598   -0.0319233
0.0249545   -0.0308879
0.0228090   -0.0298499
0.0208133   -0.0288105
0.0189576   -0.0277704
0.0172328   -0.0267306
0.0156301   -0.0256917
0.0141419   -0.0246545
0.0127612   -0.0236193
0.0114811   -0.0225866
0.0102950   -0.0215568
0.0091973   -0.0205303
0.0081831   -0.0195073
0.0072476   -0.0184881
0.0063863   -0.0174729
0.0055948   -0.0164618
0.0048693   -0.0154551
0.0042065   -0.0144528
0.0036032   -0.0134551
0.0030563   -0.0124620
0.0025628   -0.0114737
0.0021199   -0.0104901
0.0017253   -0.0095115
0.0013769   -0.0085377
0.0010723   -0.0075689
0.0008097   -0.0066051
0.0005868   -0.0056464
0.0004019   -0.0046926
0.0002537   -0.0037440
0.0001408   -0.0028004
0.0000617   -0.0018618
0.0000152   -0.0009284
0.0000000   0.0000000
0.0000173   0.0009961
0.0000692   0.0019969
0.0001558   0.0030072
0.0002783   0.0040319
0.0004383   0.0050757
0.0006379   0.0061436
0.0008800   0.0072404
0.0011683   0.0083711
0.0015070   0.0095403
0.0019009   0.0107527
0.0023554   0.0120126
0.0028762   0.0133238
0.0034695   0.0146897
0.0041416   0.0161129
0.0048985   0.0175952
0.0057460   0.0191374
0.0066895   0.0207394
0.0077335   0.0223998
0.0088822   0.0241160
0.0101380   0.0258844
0.0115021   0.0276999
0.0129746   0.0295567
0.0145545   0.0314476
0.0162393   0.0333649
0.0180246   0.0353001
0.0199049   0.0372442
0.0218742   0.0391883
0.0239247   0.0411232
0.0260474   0.0430402
0.0282332   0.0449311
0.0304725   0.0467880
0.0327551   0.0486045
0.0350706   0.0503744
0.0374097   0.0520933
0.0397636   0.0537571
0.0421238   0.0553634
0.0444826   0.0569106
0.0468336   0.0583979
0.0491717   0.0598255
0.0514930   0.0611943
0.0537938   0.0625059
0.0560719   0.0637623
0.0583265   0.0649661
0.0605575   0.0661196
0.0627655   0.0672258
0.0649511   0.0682873
0.0671154   0.0693071
0.0692598   0.0702876
0.0713863   0.0712315
0.0734970   0.0721411
0.0755935   0.0730183
0.0776775   0.0738653
0.0797502   0.0746837
0.0818128   0.0754752
0.0838664   0.0762412
0.0859126   0.0769829
0.0879525   0.0777014
0.0899870   0.0783979
0.0920174   0.0790733
0.0940444   0.0797288
0.0960694   0.0803653
0.0980938   0.0809838
0.1001200   0.0815853
0.1021490   0.0821708
0.1041860   0.0827413
0.1062320   0.0832980
0.1082910   0.0838420
0.1103680   0.0843745
0.1124680   0.0848969
0.1145960   0.0854103
0.1167580   0.0859158
0.1189620   0.0864147
0.1212150   0.0869080
0.1235260   0.0873968
0.1259020   0.0878821
0.1283550   0.0883649
0.1308940   0.0888459
0.1335290   0.0893256
0.1362730   0.0898043
0.1391360   0.0902822
0.1421310   0.0907591
0.1452710   0.0912347
0.1485690   0.0917083
0.1520370   0.0921788
0.1556880   0.0926450
0.1595330   0.0931052
0.1635840   0.0935571
0.1678520   0.0939984
0.1723460   0.0944264
0.1770730   0.0948380
0.1820380   0.0952300
0.1872430   0.0955988
0.1926900   0.0959407
0.1983750   0.0962529
0.2042920   0.0965321
0.2104320   0.0967752
0.2167850   0.0969796
0.2233370   0.0971429
0.2300760   0.0972629
0.2369840   0.0973380
0.2440450   0.0973672
0.2512440   0.0973500
0.2585610   0.0972859
0.2659820   0.0971754
0.2734920   0.0970192
0.2810750   0.0968182
0.2887200   0.0965735
0.2964170   0.0962864
0.3041540   0.0959585
0.3119260   0.0955915
0.3197270   0.0951872
0.3275540   0.0947475
0.3354040   0.0942738
0.3432770   0.0937671
0.3511740   0.0932286
0.3590950   0.0926592
0.3670470   0.0920598
0.3750350   0.0914308
0.3830670   0.0907726
0.3911490   0.0900847
0.3992940   0.0893665
0.4075110   0.0886172
0.4158160   0.0878354
0.4242230   0.0870195
0.4327490   0.0861674
0.4414130   0.0852764
0.4502350   0.0843434
0.4592370   0.0833651
0.4684400   0.0823375
0.4778670   0.0812564
0.4875390   0.0801170
0.4974790   0.0789147
0.5077050   0.0776445
0.5182330   0.0763014
0.5290760   0.0748806
0.5402420   0.0733778
0.5517340   0.0717893
0.5635500   0.0701126
0.5756810   0.0683462
0.5881140   0.0664902
0.6008290   0.0645465
0.6138020   0.0625190
0.6270050   0.0604139
0.6404050   0.0582390
0.6539570   0.0560032
0.6676090   0.0537163
0.6813030   0.0513893
0.6949730   0.0490335
0.7085520   0.0466611
0.7219720   0.0442845
0.7351680   0.0419167
0.7480800   0.0395703
0.7606520   0.0372577
0.7728360   0.0349903
0.7845920   0.0327783
0.7958850   0.0306306
0.8066920   0.0285544
0.8169980   0.0265554
0.8267950   0.0246375
0.8360880   0.0228031
0.8448880   0.0210530
0.8532070   0.0193860
0.8610660   0.0177999
0.8684930   0.0162913
0.8755160   0.0148563
0.8821680   0.0134898
0.8884780   0.0121865
0.8944800   0.0109408
0.9002050   0.0097469
0.9056840   0.0085994
0.9109460   0.0074931
0.9160180   0.0064227
0.9209220   0.0053839
0.9256820   0.0043721
0.9303150   0.0033838
0.9348400   0.0024157
0.9392700   0.0014650
0.9436180   0.0005289
0.9478930   -0.0003947
0.9521060   -0.0013075
0.9562640   -0.0022110
0.9603740   -0.0031065
0.9644430   -0.0039953
0.9684750   -0.0048784
0.9724750   -0.0057565
0.9764470   -0.0066304
0.9803950   -0.0075009
0.9843230   -0.0083687
0.9882350   -0.0092344
0.9921340   -0.0100986
0.9960230   -0.0109620
1.0000000   -0.0118460
```

But I also want to draw those vortices and streamlines over the airfoil.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question help: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482462](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482462/110998)

Comment: Or maybe this one [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/tikz-how-to-clip-out-random-coil-fragments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/tikz-how-to-clip-out-random-coil-fragments)