# a pen with varying thickness

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I can draw the Nike logo in usual way.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/w_1920,c_limit/bzl2wmsfh7kgdkufrrjq/image.jpg   
\clip (-4.5,-2.5) rectangle (4.5,2.5);
% 2 vertices
\path 
(-2.33,1.19) coordinate (A)
(3.45,1.18)  coordinate (B);

% draw the Nike logo in usual way
\fill[orange] (A)
..controls +(-116:2.45) and +(-165:4.8) .. (B)
..controls +(-153:7.4) and +(-131:3.5) .. cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I wish to draw it using `calligraphy` library of TikZ, so I need to define a based curve and a pen. A based curve is something like the following black curve

```
\def\nikecurve{(A) ..controls +(-123:3.5) and +(-158:4.8) ..(B)}  
\draw \nikecurve;
```

[image]

**Question 1:** How to define a `pen` (name nikepen) in order to draw the Nike logo by a single command

```
\pen[pen name=nikepen] .... 
\calligraphy[pen colour=orange] \nikecurve;
```

**Question 2:** Can we do it with some `pen` (or `material`) in `Asymptote` ?

***Note:***

1. The way in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/stroke-with-variable-thickness) is complex. I think `calligraphy` may be simpler.
2. I just take the Nike logo for an simple example. Solutions are expected to be applicable to general situations (see another example, Dove's logo below) as if we have a pen of fine controls of (smoothly) varying thickness and varying colors.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the calligraphy library is really suitable for something like the Nike logo as it is designed to emulate a copperplate pen with two thicknesses (light and heavy) and interpolate between the two.  The Nike logo is a continual change in thickness.  It is more suited to something like the Dove logo, and for that you would need to figure out the paths for the letters and apply the calligraphy style to that, as detailed in the documentation.