# Drawing Jet Balloon With Varying Thickness

Tags: pstricks

I would like to have a PSTricks drawing of the following picture:

[image: newton]

I have no problem drawing the arrows, but I have absolutely no idea how to draw the two ellipses do to the varying linewidth.

The drawing of the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{
  arrows = ->,
  arrowsize = 10pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2.9)(4.5,2.9)
  \psline[
    linewidth = 3\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = green
  ](-3.2,0)(-5,0)
  \psset{linewidth = 2\pslinewidth}
  \psline(-1,0)(-2.5,0)
  \psline(-0.8,0.8)(-1.5,1.5)
  \psline(0,1)(0,1.8)
  \psline(1.3,0.7)(2,1.4)
  \psline(1.3,-0.7)(2,-1.4)
  \psline(0,-1)(0,-1.8)
  \psline(-0.8,-0.8)(-1.5,-1.5)
  \psline(2.95,0.5)(4.2,0.7)
  \psline(3,0)(4.5,0)
  \psline(2.95,-0.5)(4.2,-0.7)
  \psset{linecolor = gray!50!white}
  \psline(-2.5,2.5)(-1.8,1.8)
  \psline(0,2.9)(0,2.1)
  \psline(2.9,2.2)(2.1,1.5)
  \psline(2.9,-2.2)(2.1,-1.5)
  \psline(0,-2.9)(0,-2.1)
  \psline(-2.5,-2.5)(-1.8,-1.8)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Update**

Here is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-5,-2.9)(5,2.9)
   \psset{
     arrows = ->,
     arrowsize = 10pt
   }
   {\psset{linecolor = red!50!white}
    \psline[
      linewidth = 3\pslinewidth
    ](-3.15,0)(-5,0)
    \psline(3.45,0.4)(4.7,0.7)
    \psline(3.5,0)(5,0)
    \psline(3.45,-0.4)(4.7,-0.7)}
    \psset{linewidth = 2\pslinewidth}
    \psellipse[
      fillstyle = solid,
      fillcolor = black
    ](0,0)(3,2)
    \psellipse[
      linecolor = white,
      fillstyle = solid,
      fillcolor = white
    ](0.09,0)(2.9,1.9)
    \psellipse[
      fillstyle = solid,
      fillcolor = black
    ](3.2,0)(0.2,0.5)
    \psellipse[
      linecolor = white,
      fillstyle = solid,
      fillcolor = white
    ](3.17,0)(0.17,0.4)
    \psline(-1,0)(-2.7,0)
    \psline(-0.8,0.8)(-1.5,1.5)
    \psline(0,1)(0,1.8)
    \psline(1.3,0.7)(1.93,1.35)
    \psline(1.3,-0.7)(1.93,-1.35)
    \psline(0,-1)(0,-1.8)
    \psline(-0.8,-0.8)(-1.5,-1.5)
    \psset{linecolor = gray!50!white}
    \psline(-2.4,2.5)(-1.7,1.8)
    \psline(0,2.9)(0,2.1)
    \psline(2.9,2.3)(2.15,1.55)
    \psline(2.9,-2.3)(2.15,-1.55)
    \psline(0,-2.9)(0,-2.1)
    \psline(-2.4,-2.5)(-1.7,-1.8)
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Newton's third law on a balloon.}
 \label{fig:newton-balloon}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Stroke with variable thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14283/5764)

Comment: is it supposed to be a balloon?

Comment: Check out [this example](https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Lines/lines#variable).

Comment: draw a filled ellipse, then draw another one shifted to the right filled with the background colour?

Comment: @Thruston Yes, it's a balloon. (If you provide an answer, I can accept your answer .. maybe I'll accept Werner's if he creates one I find more "elegant".)

Comment: @Werner Thanks. I'll have a look at the example with `variableLW` later tonight. (If you provide an answer, I can accept your answer .. maybe I'll accept Thorston's if he creates one I find more "elegant".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A PSTricks solution only for fun. I just provided you with the main part. Other parts are too trivial.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8.7,6)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=red,linestyle=none,linewidth=0]
    {
        \psellipse(4,3)(4,3)
        \psellipse(4.2,3)(3.8,2.8)
        \psellipse(8.45,3)(0.25,0.7)
        \psellipse(8.43,3)(0.23,0.6)
    }
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Bonus 1: Gradient Color

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-grad}

\newpsstyle{gradient}
{
    fillstyle=gradient,
    gradbegin=red,
    gradend=yellow,
    gradangle=30,
    gradmidpoint=0.5,
}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(8.7,6)
    \pscustom[style=gradient,linestyle=none,linewidth=0]
    {
        \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
        \psellipse(4,3)(4,3)
        \psellipse(4.2,3)(3.8,2.8)
        \psellipse(8.45,3)(0.25,0.7)
        \psellipse(8.43,3)(0.23,0.6)
    }
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

#### Bonus 2: Image Clipper

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=3]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(8.7,6)
\psclip{%
    \pscustom[linestyle=none,linewidth=0]
    {
        \code{/clip /eoclip load def}
        \psellipse(4,3)(4,3)
        \psellipse(4.2,3)(3.8,2.8)
        \psellipse(8.45,3)(0.25,0.7)
        \psellipse(8.43,3)(0.23,0.6)
    }}
    \rput(4,3){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I understand that this is a `pstricks` question, but I would like to mention that in `tikz` one can use `even odd rule` to produce these ellipses. Whether an analogous method exists for `pstricks` I do not know. Nonetheless, here is the `tikz` code, maybe someone can convert it to `pstricks`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[even odd rule] circle[x radius=4.15,y radius=2.1]
    (0.15,0)  circle[x radius=4,y radius=2]
    (4.8,0) circle[x radius=0.4,y radius=0.8]
    (4.85,0) circle[x radius=0.45,y radius=0.9];
 \path[every edge/.append style={very thick,-stealth}] 
  (-4.5,0) edge[ultra thick,green] ++ (-2,0)
  foreach \Angle in {45,90,...,315} 
  {(\Angle:1 and 0.5) edge (\Angle:3.75 and 1.75)
  \unless\ifnum\Angle=180\relax
  (\Angle:6 and 3) edge[gray] (\Angle:4.5 and 2.25)
  \fi}
  foreach \Angle in {20,0,-20} 
  {(4,0) ++ (\Angle:1.5) edge ++ (\Angle:1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(8.7,6)
\psellipse[linewidth=3mm,linecolor=red](4,3)(4,3)
\psellipse*[origin={0.17,0},linecolor=white](4,3)(3.8,2.9)
\psellipse[linewidth=2mm,linecolor=red](8.45,3)(0.25,0.7)
\psellipse*[origin={-0.05,0},linecolor=white](8.45,3)(0.22,0.52)
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]